# Unable to sign in to Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

We've got login/signup functionality with Google+ in our app, which worked perfectly until a few days ago. All of the sudden, every time we log in or sign up, we get statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED in onConnectionFailed. It is funny, because after showing the accounts dialog (in case of having more than one Google account on your phone), we still get the same statusCode.

I went through the Google+ documentation, just in case they had changed something in the API, but they haven't. And what's even funnier, I even downloaded their sample app from https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android and I experience the exact same thing...

Some of my colleagues have Android 5.1 already, and all of them can reproduce this error. I don't have it, but I have the Google+ app version 5.1.0.88070530 and I do experience de same.

Is anybody going through the same?

Comment: Are you experiencing this only in Android 5.1 or in earlier API versions?

Comment: both 5.1 and earlier (5.0.1, 5.0.2, 4.4.2, and 4.1.3)

Comment: Have you changed any parameter in your Activity, in your Manifest.xml file?

Comment: No. The code is exactly the same.